# Unexpected user account in 16.04LTS

Tags: permissions, virtualization, users

I am running a Toshiba A100 laptop (PSAA8E), with bog standard Ubuntu 16.04LTS.This week I was installing my new BT Smart Hub 6, which replaced the older Smart Hub 3 + separate Openreach modem. Setup failed the first time, but after a hard reset everything went off a treat.
That was until I finished and started to put the laptop into Suspend mode when I noticed that there was a new User account listed. My setup is just my User account with no Guest. The new account is called 'Libvirt Quemu'. I seem to remember Quemu as something like a memory manager in the 8/16bit days of my youth, and Google tells me that 'Libvirt Quemu' is a virtualizatation manager.
Can one of you Gurus tell me how this would require a User a/c, and why it would have been opened without my permission?
My thanks to you all in advance for taking the time to answer Newbie Q's like this.